# Api to get all locations of a zip code

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I'm in need where i can get all locations of a zip code for india .

I already tried with below link

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=110001
```

But here i get city and state name and i'm in need where by a zip code we can fetch all location like

```
{
        "Pincode": "110001",
        "Country": "INDIA",
        "City": "Central Delhi",
        "Address": "Baroda House"
    },
    {
        "Pincode": "110001",
        "Country": "INDIA",
        "City": "Central Delhi",
        "Address": "Bengali Market"
    },
    {
        "Pincode": "110001",
        "Country": "INDIA",
        "City": "Central Delhi",
        "Address": "Bhagat Singh Market"
    },
    {
        "Pincode": "110001",
        "Country": "INDIA",
        "City": "Central Delhi",
        "Address": "Connaught Place"
    },
    {
        "Pincode": "110001",
        "Country": "INDIA",
        "City": "Central Delhi",
        "Address": "Constitution House"
    },
```

I was searching for a solution in google but can't find any solutions as per my requirements . Can anyone please guide how can i get all the locations of a zip code .

Thanks in advance for your help .

Comment: I don't know much about Indian addresses, but is this what you are looking for? https://data.gov.in/catalog/all-india-pincode-directory

Comment: i tried with that already, but just a bit confused how can i find a particular zipcode also i can't see many zip code while using that .

Comment: Hmm, this thing appears to contain 19095 codes and appears to be official data. Do you have an example for any missing codes? The postal code is in the second column. When I e.g. do `grep 110001 all_india_PO_list_without_APS_offices_ver2_lat_long.csv`, I get the above results and a few more.

Comment: @sneep thanks i made it work like i wanted it to be , not sure why some guys are fast in downvoting rather then helping each other .

Answer (score 1):

Login in to site

> https://data.gov.in/catalog/all-india-pincode-directory?filters%5Bfield_catalog_reference%5D=85840&format=json&offset=0&limit=6&sort%5Bcreated%5D=desc

try

if not worked then refresh once

will work.....
worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use https://thezipcodes.com/ Get the API key from account section. Hit the get request.

```sh
https://thezipcodes.com/api/v1/search?zipCode=302010&countryCode={2digitCountryCode}&apiKey={apiKey}
```

```
{
  "success": true,
  "location": [
    {
      "country": "RU",
      "countryCode2": "RU",
      "countryCode3": "",
      "state": "Орловская Область",
      "stateCode2": "56",
      "latitude": "53.0747",
      "longitude": "36.2468",
      "zipCode": "302019",
      "city": "Орел 19"
    },
    {
      "country": "India",
      "countryCode2": "IN",
      "countryCode3": "IND",
      "state": "Rajasthan",
      "stateCode2": "24",
      "latitude": "26.7865",
      "longitude": "75.5809",
      "zipCode": "302019",
      "city": "Shyam Nagar (Jaipur)",
      "timeZone": "Indian Standard Time"
    }
  ]
}
```